# Does an electronegative atom which carries a negative formal charge withdraw electrons by induction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, formal-charge, inductive-effect

Electronegative atoms withdraw electrons by their inductuve effect. Does this fact remain true even when they are heavily loaded with electrons through negative formal charge? Are these two ideas related?

Comment: No, deprotonation changes things.